# Set expiry date for image or resource

Tags: performance, images, cache

How do I set expiry date for an image?

Is this a server side operation or can it be done as an html tag attribute?

What if I only want to set different expiry dates for different images/resources?

Answer (score 3):

You're asking about the [`Expires` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expire_header#Expires), which is sent by the server along with the HTTP response.
It is controlled by the server; for more details, consult your server's documentation.